# How to corectly bind events in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

On a page I have couple of divs, that look like this:

```
<div class="product-input">
    <input type="hidden" class="hidden-input">
    <input type="text">
    <button class="remove">X</button>
</div>
```

I'm trying to bind an event to that **remove button** with this code (simplified):

```
$('.product-input').each(function() {
    product = $(this);
    product_field = product.find('.hidden-input');

    product.on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
        product_field.val(null);
    });
});
```

It works perfectly when there is only one "product-input" div. When there is more of them, all remove buttons remove value from the hidden field from the last product-input div.

https://jsfiddle.net/ryzr40yh/

Can somebody help me finding the bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `product` and `product_field` as local variables, now they are global variables. So whichever button is clicked inside the click handler `product_field` will refer to the last input element.

```
$('.product-input').each(function() {
    var product = $(this);
    var product_field = product.find('.hidden-input');

    product.on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
        product_field.val(null);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/57gygoxp/4/)

---

But you can simplify it without using a loop as below using the siblings relationship between the clicked button and the input field

```
$('.product-input .remove').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('.hidden-input').val('')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/57gygoxp/3/)

Answer (score 5):

You dont need to iterate over the element for binding the same event. you can rather bind the event to all at once:

```
$('.product-input').on('click', '.remove', function(event) {
   $(this).prevAll('.hidden-input').val("");
});
```

If the remove buttons are not added dynamically, you will not need event delegation:

```
$('.remove').click(function(event) {
  $(this).prevAll('.hidden-input').val("");
});
```

### Working Demo